# ng-show when array length is zero

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner for AngularJS. I am trying to display "No Tag Found" during filter process with the help of "**ng-show**".

**JS:**

```
function simpleController($scope)
{
$scope.tags = ['HTML','CSS','Jquery','Bootstrap','AngularJS'];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="simpleController">
<input  class="txt" type="text" ng-model="nameText" /> 
<div>
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="myKeys in tags| filter:nameText">{{myKeys}}</li>
 </ul>
<div ng-show="!tags.length">No Tag Found</div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I type any value other than array vales, I am not able to get "No Tag Found" using the above code. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're filtering in your `ng-repeat`, you must apply the same filter for you  `ng-show`. If you don't, the `ng-show` will always refer to the full array :

```
<div ng-show="!(tags| filter:nameText).length">No Tag Found</div>
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3149/

Comment: You can also use `!count(tags)` [Click here for a modified version of Cetia's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/26922/)

Answer (score 20):

Just better use ng-hide:

```
<div ng-hide="tags.length">No Tag Found</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
 <div class="box" ng-show="team_stores.length > 0" >
```

worked for me

Answer (score 3):

easy way to create filter... demo is as below

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.friends = [
      { name: "Peter", age: 20 },
      { name: "Pablo", age: 55 },
      { name: "Linda", age: 20 },
      { name: "Marta", age: 37 },
      { name: "Othello", age: 20 },
      { name: "Markus", age: 32 }
    ];

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>welcome</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl">
   Name: <input ng-model="filter" type="text" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="friend in friends |filter:filter">{{friend.name}}</li>

        <li ng-show="!(friends| filter:filter).length">data not found</li>
        <!--<link ng-repeat="friend in friends|filter:isActive ">-->
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to use filter service, like this: `$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`, this service return new array.
you can see http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/filter/filter