# show customize message when no record match with angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added basic functionality where user can enter any student name to filter out the records from table. **It works fine.**

**However,** i need to enhance this functionality like "Show message no record found when no record found"

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchKeyword">
<tr ng-repeat="student in students |filter: searchKeyword">
<td style="text-align: left;" width="296;">{{student.FirstName}} {{student .LastName}}</td>
```

Any hint please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-show when array length is zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076570/ng-show-when-array-length-is-zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following no ?

```
<div ng-show="!(students.length > 0)">No Students Found! Call the COPS!</div>
```

This is just a conditional view. Which as you can see, will only display id the results count is not greater than 0! :)

Or even better :

```
<div ng-show="!(students| filter:searchKeyword).length">No Students Found</div>
```

ref: [ng-show when array length is zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076570/ng-show-when-array-length-is-zero)

Comment: I am using <tr> and not <div> and secondly in your answer you skipped ng-repeat. Why?

Comment: @immirza because this stays within the ng-repeat view model. Why would you have 2x `ng-repeat`'s ? This is a notification placeholder for the user.. You can have it as a `<tr>` if you wish.

Comment: @ Pogrindis, thanks you for sharing the fiddler and reference to an existing question. I got now what you tried to explain above. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily **save a result of a filter** like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in (filteredStudents = students | filter: searchKeyword)">
```

And then it's just as easy as:

```
<span ng-show="filteredStudents.length === 0">no record found when no record found</span>
```